# Drools Workbench - How to push back changes to a cloned repository?

Tags: git, drools, kie-server

I'm working with Drools-Workbench and Kie Execution Server.
Both are installed with Docker from these hub resources:

https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/kie-server-showcase/
https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/drools-workbench-showcase/

From Drools Workbench I cloned my github repository and made some changes.
Now I want to commit and push these changes back to the origin.
When I run the bash process on my drools-wb container I see the
.niogit folder and inside it my cloned git folder.

What is the way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Workbench doesn't support pushing to other repos.  You need to clone the KWB repo and then push to the github repo from the new clone.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, my company workbench (version 6.4.0.GA) is configured to access using ldap auth. For some reason, git pushes are not working with my ldap user. So I create a new user (called commiter) from Home/User Management, and assign them to develop role.

Then, on my local workbench, I cloned the remote repository, using Authoring/Administration/Repositories/Clone Repository, using the git url, like

```
git://my-company-wb-url:9418/my-project
```

Then, I changed on .niogit/my-project.git/configure the lines:

```
#   url = git://my-company-wb-url:9418/my-project
    url = ssh://commiter@my-company-wb-url:8001/my-project
```

Also, I commented:

```
#   sshCommand = ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss
```

Because the error "Bad protocol 2 host key algorithms '+ssh-dss'"

Finally,

```
cd .niogit
git --git-dir=my-project.git/ push
```

And thats all.

Hope it helps.